# 'Arsonist' is to 'fire' as what is to 'water'?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

According to Merriam-Webster, an arsonist is a person that engages in "the willful or malicious burning of property (as a building) especially with criminal or fraudulent intent".

Flooding can also cause serious damage to buildings or other property.  Although it is probably significantly less common, I could imagine that a person might maliciously flood property with criminal or fraudulent intent.

For example, if the residents are vacationing away from home, it would be easy enough for a person to cause serious water damage to a house by turning on all water spouts and plugging all drains.  This occurs in the movie *Home Alone*:

> **Harry:** [Marv brings a load of stolen goods from the Murphy household to the van and Harry sees him laughing] What's so funny? What are you laughing at? You did it again didn't you? You left the water running. What's wrong with you? Why do you do that? I told you not to do it.
>   **Marv:** Harry, it's our calling card!
>   **Harry:** Calling card.
>   **Marv:** All the great ones leave their mark. We're the wet bandits!

Is there a word for such a person?  In other words, *arsonist* is to *fire* as what is to *water* / *flood*?

Comment: How about a couple of neologisms:  "redundantist" and "eluviest," from Latin redundo and eluvies, flood.

Comment: This particular action is not common enough to have been given a name. This will result in most answers being neologisms.

Comment: "I understand fire insurance, but how do you start a flood?"

Comment: @user867 I don't understand the reference that you seem to be making.

Comment: [Waterbender](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Waterbending).

Comment: @HenryDeYoung, the quotation appears to be what a person familiar with arson-for-profit might say about flood insurance.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung jwpat7 is correct - it's the punchline to a old joke, but the humour can (hopefully) be understood even without the buildup. I meant it to reinforce Mitch's point about criminal inundation being less common than arson by pointing out that the former is more effort to organise than the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *arson* derives from the Latin word for burning; the Latin word for flooding is *inundo*. So your closest match is something like *inundationist*, though I don't think this word is attested, and *inundate* isn't considered criminal.

Comment: Of course it is criminal, if you broke the village dam and destroyed the ripening harvests.

Comment: I also like @rhetorician's suggestion of *eluviest*, similar to your *inundationist*.  Thanks!

Comment: One can't just make up candidates and call them 'words'.

Answer (score 4):

*[Swamper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swamper#Noun)* is a possibility, in its sense 3,  “Someone or something that swamps or overwhelms”.  Also consider  *[flooder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flooder#Noun)*, a word of more recent origin meaning  “A person who floods message boards with unwanted or repetitive comments”.  *[Drencher](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drencher)* means  “One who, or that which, drenches”.  *Deluger* would have similar meaning but isn't in most dictionaries.  Related:  *[dambusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Chastise)*, those who bust dams, causing floods.

Comment: Yeah, I think they're all just dam criminals.

Comment: I prefer the suggestions of rhetorician and personak, but +1 just for the reference to the Dambusters of 617 squadron.  The book by Paul Brickhill is excellent, if you haven't read it!  (Incidentally, the motto of 617 squadron is "Après moi, le déluge".)

Comment: The U in ELU stands for 'usage'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, true; so?

Comment: 'Arsonist' is widely used (sadly) to mean '[a person who] engages in "the willful or malicious burning of property (as a building) especially with criminal or fraudulent intent" '. Are you seriously suggesting that any of your suggestions is _widely used_ (the 'usage', 'standard usage' requirement) to mean '[a person who] engages in "the wilful or malicious flooding of property (as a building) especially with criminal or fraudulent intent" '? The answers above are mere ballpark (or perhaps better, carpark). Anyone imagining that criminal B would be termed a 'swamper' while criminal A was ...

Comment: termed an arsonist has little command of the language. But sadly this answer could easily be interpreted to encourage such a belief.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Re "Are you seriously suggesting that any of your suggestions is widely used (...) to mean...", no.  Note, OP asks, "Is there a word for such a person?" rather than if there's a *widely used* such word.  In my answer, I said "Here's a possibility..." and "Also consider..." and presented a few words, rather than supposing the question fully answered.  Feel free to provide a proper answer to the question.

Comment: 'Arsonist' is to 'fire' as 'swamper' is to 'water'.  I'd just delete.